# Flutter Instagram login and cookies

Tags: flutter, session, cookies, webview, instagram

I want to let users to login their instagrams and see their statistics in my app.
I created a webview inside to help them login.
But in the app, I am getting the cookie differently.

With:

```
onPageFinished: (String url) async {
                  String sourceCode = await controller
                      .evaluateJavascript("document.body.outerHTML");
                  if (url == "https://www.instagram.com/" &&
                      sourceCode.contains("window._sharedData =")) {
                    String cookies =
                        await controller.evaluateJavascript("document.cookie");
                    //new intent
                   
                    print(cookies);
                    setState(() {
                      visibility = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
```

I am checking that if the redirection is going through instagram.com, login is successful. After that with the "document.cookie", I am getting the cookie.

The problem is with "document.cookie", I am getting a short cookie that is not useful for queries on instagram.

In the browser it has a cookie starting with : ig_did (it is a long one), but in my app,  I have a cookie starting with : "mid=".

I am thinking about how to get or generate that long cookie, if I cant, I am not able to request end points.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved with using webview_cookie_manager 2.0.1;
document.cookie is not enough to get all the cookies from the url.